# Django, models form Not saving data in database

Tags: python, django

I am new to django, I created a form to save Data into my database but it not working corectly, I got no error but data is not sent in database. Thanks for helping!

views.py

```
@login_required()
def data(request):
    if request.POST == "POST":
        form = CreatePost(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect(data)
    else:
        form = CreatePost()
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "sms/data.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
class CreatePost(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["title", "content"]
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

data.html

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
      <pre></pre>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" value="Submit">Data</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure your form is valid?  Are you displaying `{{form.errors}}` in your template so you see if there are errors?

Comment: Ah: `if request.POST == "POST"` is always false. It's probably this simple typo you made which causes your issue.

Comment: If i write ```{{form.errors}} ``` in template, my form is not shown on my page, I updated my post with my template

Comment: did you change the line `if request.POST`?????

Comment: Florin's answer was first and correct. He already mentioned to fix `request.POST` to `request.method`. You should mark his answer correct, not the other one.

Comment: yes it is True!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
@login_required()
def data(self, request):
 if request.method == "POST": #this line
    form = CreatePost(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False) #new line
        post.author = self.request.user #this line
        post.save() #this line
        return redirect(data)
else:
    form = CreatePost()
context = {
    "form": form
}
return render(request, "sms/data.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.POST == "POST":
```

Should instead be:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```